# How to share data between browser tabs using session storage in react js?

Tags: reactjs

How can i share data between browser tabs. I'm using `sessionStorage`  to store my token. When i click next tab it will be cleared ,I'm also use `localStorage` it work fine but i want to clear all storage data when close browser.

I'm using react js

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  localStorage.removeItem(key); // key to be provided
  return '';
};
```

This will clear the particular `key` from local storage after you close the tab.

Also, Why don't you go for cookies ? If you domain and subdomain is same then the cookie can be shared between multiple tabs and if no expiry is set for the cookie then it will expire after the session.

Comment: This will clear the current token whenever a tab is closed, though - if tab A is closed, tab B will no longer be able to see the token in storage

Comment: I think the requirement is bit unclear then. @naseeba c can you please clarify ?

Comment: @keshav This code not work for me. it clear token when reload page

Comment: i never use cookie it secure?

Comment: @CertainPerformance i want clear my token only browser close

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) to communicate between tabs. When the page loads, open a channel and send a message requesting a token. If other instances of the app are open, they can listen for the message and reply with it. Otherwise, if no message is received after, say, 1/4 of a second, make a request for a new token, and save it in a variable.

Regardless of what happens above, also have the created channel listen for token requests. When such a request is received, post a message back including the token.